# Getting textbox value(or itself) in javascript results in null

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

code:

```
<input name="xy" size="2" type="text" />
```

this is meant to be a textbox, looks like and functions like one.

js:

```
  alert(document.getElementById("xy"));
```

and this returns null. If I try to get value of it or whatever, I simply get nothing.

Any reason ? (p.s: javascript works fine and its external)

Comment: There is no element with an `id` of "xy", so `getElementById` doesn't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set an id :

```
<input id="xy" name="xy" size="2" type="text" />
```

getElementById take the id attribute, not the name.

Answer (score 0):

As our friend Ren said:

getElementById gets by the id, so you should set and id

But if you need to use the name atribute you could use:
document.getElementsByName